# Visual C# 2010 Express Edition Build Application Not Correct

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

OK, so I am making a sample Tic-Tac-Toe game.  I then go to build my application, and everything works correctly.  I then go to make some changes, and the changes don't register.  For example, I delete a button in the Form1.Designer file, but when I build it, it still shows the button I deleted.  Or when I change the value of a int variable, it still shows the previous value upon building the application.  This has happened multiple times, and I am really getting frustrated.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, I figured it out.  The problem was with the debug build, so I deleted it and rebuilt my program- and voila!  It worked.  If anyone else has this problem, navigate to your project folder and head over to the debug folder.  Then delete the contents, and rebuild!  It should work, as it did for me.